# Custom Hibernate business validation model: possible risks

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jpa, orm

I'm planning to create a custom validation model that depends on the Pre and Post Listeners of Hibernate.

Each Validation class should contain a business rule (not input checking) that needs to be checked before doing an insert, update or delete.
That's why it depends on Listeners like `PreInsertEventListener`, `PreUpdateEventListener`, `PreInsertDeleteListener`.

A validation class sometimes needs to check something in the DB. I've read in other posts that it is not advised to insert or update something from a Listener? But I'm planning to do only read-only calls.

To resume:

- Validation class is related to one specific entity;
- Validaton class is invoked by a Hibernate `Listener`;
- Validation class might do some 'read-only' calls in DB;
- Validation class is executed within same Hibernate `Session` and `Transaction`;
- When a rule is not satisfied, some `RuntimeException` will be thrown causing a rollback of the current `Transaction`;

The advantage of this concept is that all business rules can be put in Validation classes which are specifically related to one entity. This avoids business rules to be spread over different Services.

What do you think of this approach? Are there any disadvantages/risks (specifically Hibernate related) wich I need to take care of?

Answer (score 0):

I think the important thing here is predicting that your validation rules will only be specific to the entity being persisted. Its quite possible that you will run into situations that require data from parent/child entities to validate or to fetch related data.

The business rules spread over different services is a real world case, where usually to validate an entity you need to invoke different services. For example, if you want to persist a debit transaction for an account, you want to validate if the account holder exists, account is in a valid state & account has sufficient balance.